# C# Json.Net: {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean[,]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Boolean]'."}

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialise a complex object, which can contain instances of that same class (WorldInstance, which can contain more WorldInstances), but it's throwing this exception and I have no idea why, or how to fix it.

I know this is a bit vague, but I have no idea what information is needed, so I will post anything that is asked of me.

EDIT 1: Here's the entire class I'm trying to serialise.
http://pastebin.com/QTNH1HZH

I think it's failing on the discoveredTiles, on line 691, even though it shouldn't be doing anything with that data.

Comment: You're trying to cast a single boolean value to a collection of boolean values. Either way, show us your code you're trying to deserialise

Comment: Added a pastebin link, because the class is huge.

Comment: Can you please share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, complete traceback, and inner exception if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to make Json.NET deserialize a get-only array property `discoveredTiles`, as is shown in the following simplified version of your class:

```
public class WorldInstance
{
    protected WorldTile[,] m_Tiles;
    protected bool[,] m_Discovered;

    public WorldInstance(WorldTile[,] tiles)
    {
        m_Tiles = tiles;
        m_Discovered = new bool[m_Tiles.GetLength(0), m_Tiles.GetLength(1)];
    }

    public WorldTile[,] tiles
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Tiles;
        }
    }

    public bool[,] discoveredTiles
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Discovered;
        }
    }
}

public class WorldTile
{
}
```

This is currently not implemented even if the array is pre-allocated and has the same length as the JSON array, since Json.NET will try to *add* deserialized items to the pre-allocated array, which is of course impossible.  (Note that the `tiles` property will get deserialized by passing it to the constructor, matching the JSON property name to the constructor argument name.)

For a 1d array property, the exception thrown explains this problem:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.
   at System.SZArrayHelper.Add[T](T value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionWrapper`1.Add(T item) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionWrapper.cs:line 76
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionWrapper`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionWrapper.cs:line 194
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2030
```

But for a 2d array the less illuminating `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

You have two workarounds for this problem:

1. Add a protected constructor to `WorldInstance` that includes a `bool[,] discoveredTiles` argument and mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm), for instance:

   ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   protected WorldInstance(WorldTile[,] tiles, bool[,] discoveredTiles)
   {
       if (tiles == null || discoveredTiles == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException();
       // Ensure the tiles and discoveredTiles arrays have the same sizes
       if (tiles.GetLength(0) != discoveredTiles.GetLength(0) || tiles.GetLength(1) != discoveredTiles.GetLength(1))
           throw new InvalidOperationException("tiles.GetLength(0) != discoveredTiles.GetLength(0) || tiles.GetLength(1) != discoveredTiles.GetLength(1)");
       m_Tiles = tiles;
       m_Discovered = discoveredTiles;
   }
   ```

   Note that the parameter name `discoveredTiles` must be the same as the corresponding serialized property name.
2. Add a private or protected setter for `discoveredTiles` and mark it with [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm):

   ```
   [JsonProperty]
   public bool[,] discoveredTiles
   {
       get
       {
           return m_Discovered;
       }
       protected set
       {
           if (value == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException();
           // Ensure the tiles and discoveredTiles arrays have the same sizes
           if (tiles != null && tiles.GetLength(0) != value.GetLength(0) || tiles.GetLength(1) != value.GetLength(1))
               throw new InvalidOperationException("tiles != null && tiles.GetLength(0) != value.GetLength(0) || tiles.GetLength(1) != value.GetLength(1)");
           m_Discovered = value;
       }
   }
   ```